# python2.7: replace multiple char with their respective char

Tags: python-2.7, replace

i have a script that process text

in this script there a def that needs to replace chars with others

for example:

```
@ => [ at ]
- => --
_ = (space)
\ => /
```

my idea is to do:

```
def rrr(str):
  return str
         .replace('@', '[ at ]').
         .replace('-', '--').
         .replace('_', ' ').
         .replace('\', '/')
```

is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

```
def rrr(s, reps):
    for src,t in reps.iteritems():
        s = s.replace(src,t)
    return s
```

Use it this way:

```
replacements = {'@' : '[ at ]',
                '-' : '--',
                '_' : ' ',
                '\\' : '/'
               }
rrr(some_string, replacements)
```

Comment: I added tons of replacements but this one does not work. I have @@ i need to replace with ++ but in my string I get: [ at ] [ at ] why? -- @ is first and @@ is second

Comment: @Erik: this happens because the `@` got evaluated before the `@@`. If you want to handle those cases, I'd recommend going with a list of tuples instead of a dict